# C# Serialization of Referenced object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm having problems serializing an object which has been added to my project via a Service Reference to XML.

The object which is referenced via the service reference has the structure:

```
public class GetProspectsContactStatusParametersV1
{
    public GetProspectsContactStatusParametersV1()
    {
        Version = 1;
    }

    public int Version { get; set; }

    public ProspectIds ProspectIDs { get; set; }

    public InterestIds InterestIDs { get; set; }

    public class ProspectIds
    {
        private List<int> _prospectIds = new List<int>();
        [XmlElement("ProspectId")]
        public List<int> Items
        {
            get { return _prospectIds; }
            set { _prospectIds = value; }
        }
    }

    public class InterestIds
    {
        private List<int> _interestIds = new List<int>();
        [XmlElement("InterestId")]
        public List<int> Items
        {
            get { return _interestIds; }
            set { _interestIds = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

This code forms part of a Web Service project which I reference in another application. Using the reference in the other project I create an instance of the above object as follows:

```
var request = new ProspectsWebServiceMetadata.GetProspectsContactStatusParametersV1();
request.Version = 1;
request.InterestIDs = new ProspectsWebServiceMetadata.InterestIds
{
    2,3,4,5
};
```

And I then try to Serialize this object to XML using a basic XmlSerializer:

```
public static string ToXmlString(object source)
{
    using (StringWriter sww = new StringWriter())
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(source.GetType());

        ser.Serialize(writer, source);

        return sww.ToString();
    }
}
```

The XML that gets created is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <GetProspectsContactStatusParametersV1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Version>1</Version>
    <InterestIDs>
        <int>2</int>
        <int>3</int>
        <int>4</int>
        <int>5</int>
    </InterestIDs>
```

The part of the XML above within "InterestIDs" **should** have "InterestID" instead of "int".

The code generated as part of importing the reference seems to indicate that it should serialize correctly, but obviously it does not:

```
 [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="InterestIds", Namespace="http://www.testing.com/", ItemName="InterestId")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class InterestIds : System.Collections.Generic.List<int> {
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute in the final snippet for the `CollectionDataContractAttribute` is actually marking the data for the `DataContractSerializer`, not the `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: From your suggestion, I found the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348240/xml-serialization-using-datacontractserializer-and-xmlserializer?rq=1. Once I added the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` the serialization works correctly.